# is $f(A-B) = f(A) - f(B)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

We have some function $f: X  \to Y$. $A,B$ are subsets of $X$. I need to either prove or disprove the following:

$f(A-B) = f(A) - f(B)$.

I understand that such a function has to be injective. I'm unable to arrive at a counter example and don't know how to prove this.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If $f$ is constant and $B\subset A, B\ne A,$ you have a counterexample.

Comment: What is $Y\\\\\\$?

Comment: @mfl Why is $B⊂A,B\neq A$ necessary? Surely just $f\neq\phi$?

Comment: $Y$ is the image space

Comment: @Shuri2060 Actually, it is only need $A\setminus B\ne \emptyset.$

Comment: @mfl Why? Let $A - B = \phi$. Then the LHS is $f(\phi)$. If $f$ is non-zero, then the equation doesn't hold.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f: \{ 1, 2 \} \to \{ 1 \}$; let $A := \{ 1 \}$; let $B := \{ 2 \}$. Then $f(A\setminus B) = f(\{ 1 \}) = \{ 1 \}$ but $f(A)\setminus f(B) = \{ 1 \} \setminus \{ 1 \} = \varnothing$.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample:

$X = \{ 1,2 \}$

$A =X$

$B = \{ 1 \}$

$Y = \{ 0 \}$

$f(1)=f(2)=0$

Then:

$f(A-B)=\{ 0 \}$

$f(A)-f(B)= \{ 0 \} - \{ 0 \} = \emptyset$